# How do I start using Xiki in Emacs?

Tags: ruby, emacs, editor, xiki

Trying to get [xiki](http://xiki.org/) to work.

It is installed:

```
$ xiki directory
/Users/joshcheek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/xiki-0.6.3/
```

The shell script that moves all the files around executed successfully AFAIK, but I closed that shell, so can't show its output. Nothing jumped out at me about being wrong, though.

It looks like the server is running:

```
$ xiki status
xiki_process.rb: running [pid 93257]
```

I have emacs installed (I installed this before installing xiki), and set up the init file:

```
$ cat ~/.el4r/init.rb 
# Beginning of the el4r block:
# RCtool generated this block automatically. DO NOT MODIFY this block!
# This is the el4r initialization file.
# End of the el4r block.
# User-setting area is below this line.
# User-setting area is below this line.

$LOAD_PATH.unshift "/Users/joshcheek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/xiki-0.6.3/lib"
require 'xiki'
Xiki.init

KeyBindings.keys   # Use default key bindings
Themes.use "Default"  # Use xiki theme
```

But when I run emacs, it splits the screen and places this error in the bottom:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/joshcheek/.emacs':

error: el4r-instance is dead.

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

when I press Option-l (also tried Escape l, in case option wasn't meta), nothing appears to happen (When I do it in the welcome window pane, it says it is read only, when I do it in the bottom one that says xiki is dead, it just doesn't do anything). Going back to the console, `xiki status` still says it is running with the same pid.

There are two logs, each with the same problem:

```
$ tail /tmp/el4r-joshcheek.9*
==> /tmp/el4r-joshcheek.92157.log <==
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:797:in `call'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:797:in `readline'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:797:in `el4r_recv'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:790:in `el4r_get'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:768:in `block in el4r_wait_expr'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:836:in `el4r_with_call'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:765:in `el4r_wait_expr'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:760:in `el4r_wait_expr_loop'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:1102:in `<main>'
2012-09-12 23:50:14 -0500:Exiting.

==> /tmp/el4r-joshcheek.93192.log <==
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:797:in `call'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:797:in `readline'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:797:in `el4r_recv'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:790:in `el4r_get'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:768:in `block in el4r_wait_expr'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:836:in `el4r_with_call'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:765:in `el4r_wait_expr'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:760:in `el4r_wait_expr_loop'
  from /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/el4r-instance:1102:in `<main>'
2012-09-12 23:53:41 -0500:Exiting.
```

I don't know how I'm supposed to be able to load it up, I assumed I just start emacs, and I can begin double clicking things like the word `table` so far it doesn't do this, but I don't think it's correctly talking to emacs.

When I look at info in the emacs gui, it says it is version 24.2 (installed from [here](http://emacsformacosx.com/)), when I do `emacs --version` on the console, it says it is version 22.1.1 I can troubleshoot this and try to get them both to version 24, but I don't even know if this is what the problem is (though I'd probably prefer to use these from the console).

I tried finding docs about how to get going with it, but there didn't seem to be much in that way. Tried joining the Google group, I would have asked there, but my membership is pending.

I just want to be able to try out the stuff from the video.

Comment: You also read Matz's tweet about Xiki? :)

Comment: A friend of mine sent it to me https://twitter.com/bashrw/status/246060585496764416

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I was guessing emacs is trying to load the system ruby's gemset while everything is installed through RVM on 1.9.3, but I tried the steps in the link posted by @ayckoster, but I'm still getting "error: el4r-instance is dead" as well as the "exists?" error mentioned by Joshua.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have everything installed.  If you are using rvm, did you change the ruby version when you installed everything? I had the same problem with emacs saying el4r instance is dead when I started emacs with rvm using a different ruby than what I installed el4r with.

Comment: I installed and ran everything on ruby ruby-1.9.3-p194, this is my rvm default.

Comment: What was your solution? Do you just install xiki in each RVM gemset you have or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue today. I finally installed `el4r` separately and it works fine now. See http://www.rubyist.net/~rubikitch/computer/el4r/index.en.html#label:10. You might need to `sudo` some of the commands depending of your system.

Also, before executing `ruby -S el4r-rctool...`, you need to change the directory to `/path_to_where_you_downloaded_el4r/el4r-1.0.4/bin/`.

Comment: Hmm, reinstalled it using `gem install el4r` ( I don't need sudo since I'm on rvm. I have all of this installed on my default ruby in rvm `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194 --default`. Tried setting `export EL4R_HOME="$HOME/.el4r"`, didn't seem to help. Tried `el4r-rctool -p` and then `el4r-rctool -i`, which executed successfully but didn't seem to do anything. `el4r-instance` just hangs. `el4r` and `el4r-runtest` blow up `/Users/joshcheek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/el4r/exec-el4r.rb:85:in `exist?': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have installed el4r the wrong way or from the wrong source. I have created a similar question here: [How can I install el4r in emacs 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312698/how-can-i-install-el4r-in-emacs-24/13313450#13313450)

You will encounter problems if you have installed el4r previous to xiki (manually). Either follow the instructions on the link I have provided above or uninstall the el4r you have installed currently and re-install xiki exactly as described on their [page](https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki).